# how to make this type of table that has no border in bottom

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxn8N.png)
how to make this table using css

i am not able to fix it
we have to make this table without border at end
i am not able to fix it
i am not able to fix it
we have to make this table without border at endi am not able to fix it
we have to make this table without border at endi am not able to fix it
we have to make this table without border at end
we have to make this table without border at end

Comment: When you say "border at the end", do you mean the right-most border or the bottom border?

Comment: if you are using bootstrap 4 so use this [Link-For Bootstrap table template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/)

Answer (score 0):

To make a invisible border, set the BORDER attribute to 0

```html
<table Border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code in Fiddle.I had added no-border class to the td

```css
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.no-border{
  border-bottom:0;
  border-left:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="no-border"></td>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>320</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```